# Add subview to lower left corner

Tags: objective-c, subview

I'm trying to add a button as subview to the lower right corner. It will work with x, y coordinates but i think that's not a good way to do so.

I need to add the button to the left bottom of the view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work by playing with the `autoresizingMask` property of your button. Depending of what you want:

**Bottom left corner:**

```
yourButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

**Bottom right corner:**

```
 yourButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

if you rotate you device your button will then stay on its corner.

You still need to set-up once the coordinates(by either setting the `frame` or `center` property) of your button once for example when your view is loaded in your viewController.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer. I tried it out but it's not working. (i think i'm doing something wrong). I set the pos with 
    _addButton.center  = CGPointMake(30.0f, 30.0f); and then applied your code, but the button still stays at 30, 30 top left.

Comment: no what you are doing is ok... You need to put more height so it set on the bottom left. Once you will rotate your device it will stay there because the button height will be automatically ajust with the mask I recommended you to use

Comment: you can use self.frame.size.height - 30 if you want 30 points offset

Comment: Ok, so if i set e.g. 200.0f height and the view will be resized it will automatically resize that to something smaller.? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use cgrectmake so directly set the x and y 
With:

CGRectMake(x,self.view.bounds.size.height-offsetfrombottom,....);

This would be it for the left button
The right button also should have self.view.bounds.size.width-rightSideOffset for x